# tikz: Mean as Center of gravity

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Desired Output**

[image]

**My MWE**

Borrowed the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147496/4821).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-30,transform shape]
            \draw (-0.2,0) rectangle (15.5,1);
            %% lower divisions
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,15}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.2)node[above,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,14.9}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.075);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,14.5}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,0.15);
            }
            % Upper divisions
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.8)node[below,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,5.9}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.925);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,5.5}{
            \draw (\x in,1) -- (\x in,0.85);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your try and the desired output are not really alike…

Comment: I am confused. -I do not see any question!

Comment: Presumably they are not really alike because the so-called MWE is copied without modification from the linked answer. No attempt at all to adapt it - not even by changing the colour or eliminating the rotation...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Improved version:

[image]

Now everything is done using just a `Balance` environment (the mandatory argument is the comma separated list to place the weights) and a `\Cotas` command (for the help lines); for example, the image above was produced simply by saying

```
\begin{Balance}{1,2,3,5,7,9}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{3,4,8}
\Cotas{4,8}
\Cotas[2]{3}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{2,4,6,8,10}
\Cotas{4,8}
\Cotas[2]{2,10}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{1,4,5,8,10,12}
\Cotas{5,8}
\Cotas[2]{4,10}
\Cotas[3]{1,12}
\end{Balance}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{249,255,195}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{251,245,160}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{239,178,107}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{214,96,0}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{191,203,224}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{105,103,161}

% A pic path for the weights
\tikzset{
Peso/.pic={
  \coordinate (wll) at (-0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wlr) at (0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wul) at (-0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \coordinate (wur) at (0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \draw[fill=color5] 
    (wll) -- (wlr) -- (wur) -- (wul) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=color6]
    (wur) --
    ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
    ++(-75:0.4cm) --
    (wlr) --
    cycle;  
  }
}

\newcounter{Number}
\newcounter{Suma}
\newlength\XFactor
\setlength\XFactor{1cm}

\def\RectHt{1cm}
\def\Angle{20}
\def\Corr{0pt}
\def\Gap{6pt}


\newenvironment{Balance}[1]
{%
  \medskip\par\noindent
  \setcounter{Number}{0}%
  \setcounter{Suma}{0}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\XFactor]
    \foreach \Valor in {#1}
    {
      \pic at (\Valor,\RectHt) {Peso};
      \stepcounter{Number}%
      \addtocounter{Suma}{\Valor}
      \xdef\Steps{\Valor}
    }
    \def\RectWd{\numexpr\Steps+1\relax*\XFactor}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\FulcrumCoord}{\theSuma/\theNumber}

% The ruled rectangle
    \coordinate (ll) at (0,0);%\node at ([xshift=-10pt]ll) {\FulcrumCoord};
    \coordinate (ur) at (\RectWd,\RectHt);
    \draw[fill=color1]
      (ll) rectangle (ur);
    \draw[fill=color2] 
      (ur) -- 
      ++(-\Angle:6pt) -- 
      ++(0,-\RectHt) -- 
      ++(-\RectWd,0) -- 
      (ll) --
      ++(\RectWd,0) --
      cycle;   
    \foreach \Valor in {1,...,\Steps}
      \draw (\Valor,1) -- ++(0pt,-5pt) node[below] {\Valor};  
    \draw (\RectWd,0) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);

% The fulcrum
    \draw[fill=color3] 
      (\FulcrumCoord,0) --
      ++(240:1) --
      ++(1,0) coordinate (aux) --
      cycle;
    \draw[fill=color4]  
      (\FulcrumCoord,0) --
      ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
      ++(-60:1) --
      ++(-1,0) --
      ++(180-\Angle:6pt) --
      ++(1,0) --
      cycle;
    \draw (aux) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);
    \coordinate (cotaFulc) 
      at (\FulcrumCoord,\RectHt);
    \draw[color4] 
      (\FulcrumCoord,0) --
      ++(0,2pt) 
        node[above=-2pt] {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\FulcrumCoord}};  
}
{\end{tikzpicture}\medskip\par\noindent}

\newcommand\Cotas[2][2]{
\draw 
  (\FulcrumCoord,\RectHt+#1\Corr+\number\numexpr#1-1\relax\Gap) -- 
  ++(0,10pt);
  \foreach \Valor in {#2}
    {
      \draw 
        (\Valor,\RectHt+#1\Corr+\number\numexpr#1-1\relax\Gap) -- 
          coordinate (cota\Valor) 
        ++(0,10pt);
      \draw[<->,>=latex,help lines] 
        (cotaFulc|-cota\Valor) -- 
          node[fill=white] {$\pgfmathparse{\Valor-\FulcrumCoord}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}$} 
        (cota\Valor);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Balance}{1,2,3,5,7,9}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{3,4,8}
\Cotas{4,8}
\Cotas[2]{3}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{2,4,6,8,10}
\Cotas{4,8}
\Cotas[2]{2,10}
\end{Balance}

\begin{Balance}{1,4,5,8,10,12}
\Cotas{5,8}
\Cotas[2]{4,10}
\Cotas[3]{1,12}
\end{Balance}

\end{document}
```

### First version:

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{249,255,195}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{251,245,160}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{239,178,107}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{214,96,0}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{191,203,224}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{105,103,161}

\tikzset{
Peso/.pic={
  \coordinate (wll) at (-0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wlr) at (0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wul) at (-0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \coordinate (wur) at (0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \draw[fill=color5] 
    (wll) -- (wlr) -- (wur) -- (wul) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=color6]
    (wur) --
    ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
    ++(-75:0.4cm) --
    (wlr) --
    cycle;  
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.3cm]
\def\RectWd{13cm}
\def\RectHt{1cm}
\def\Angle{20}

% The weights
\foreach \Valor in {3,4,8}
  \pic at (\Valor,\RectHt) {Peso};

% The ruled rectangle
\coordinate (ll) at (0,0);
\coordinate (ur) at (\RectWd,\RectHt);

\draw[fill=color1]
  (ll) rectangle (ur);
\draw[fill=color2] 
  (ur) -- 
  ++(-\Angle:6pt) -- 
  ++(0,-\RectHt) -- 
  ++(-\RectWd,0) -- 
  (ll) --
  ++(\RectWd,0) --
  cycle;   
\foreach \Valor in {1,...,9}
  \draw (\Valor,1) -- ++(0pt,-5pt) node[below] {\Valor};  
\draw (\RectWd,0) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);

% The fulcrum
\draw[fill=color3] 
  (5,0) --
  ++(240:1) --
  ++(1,0) coordinate (aux) --
  cycle;
\draw[fill=color4]  
  (5,0) --
  ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
  ++(-60:1) --
  ++(-1,0) --
  ++(180-\Angle:6pt) --
  ++(1,0) --
  cycle;
\draw (aux) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);

% the helping lines
\begin{scope}[
>=latex,
help lines
]
\foreach \Valor in {4,5,8}
  \draw (\Valor,1.5) -- coordinate (cota\Valor) ++(0,14pt);
\draw[<->] (cota4) -- node[fill=white] {$-1$} (cota5);
\draw[<->] (cota5) -- node[fill=white] {$3$} (cota8);
\foreach \Valor in {3,5}
  \draw (\Valor,2.2) -- coordinate (cota\Valor) ++(0,14pt);
\draw[<->] (cota3) -- node[fill=white] {$-2$} (cota5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And one can easily produce different arrangements for the system:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{249,255,195}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{251,245,160}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{239,178,107}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{214,96,0}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{191,203,224}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{105,103,161}

\tikzset{
Peso/.pic={
  \coordinate (wll) at (-0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wlr) at (0.4cm,0);
  \coordinate (wul) at (-0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \coordinate (wur) at (0.3cm,0.4cm);
  \draw[fill=color5] 
    (wll) -- (wlr) -- (wur) -- (wul) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=color6]
    (wur) --
    ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
    ++(-75:0.4cm) --
    (wlr) --
    cycle;  
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.3cm]
\def\RectWd{14.3cm}
\def\RectHt{1cm}
\def\Angle{20}

% The weights
\foreach \Valor in {2,4,6,8,10}
  \pic at (\Valor,\RectHt) {Peso};

% The ruled rectangle
\coordinate (ll) at (0,0);
\coordinate (ur) at (\RectWd,\RectHt);

\draw[fill=color1]
  (ll) rectangle (ur);
\draw[fill=color2] 
  (ur) -- 
  ++(-\Angle:6pt) -- 
  ++(0,-\RectHt) -- 
  ++(-\RectWd,0) -- 
  (ll) --
  ++(\RectWd,0) --
  cycle;   
\foreach \Valor in {1,...,10}
  \draw (\Valor,1) -- ++(0pt,-5pt) node[below] {\Valor};  
\draw (\RectWd,0) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);

% The fulcrum
\draw[fill=color3] 
  (6,0) --
  ++(240:1) --
  ++(1,0) coordinate (aux) --
  cycle;
\draw[fill=color4]  
  (6,0) --
  ++(-\Angle:6pt) --
  ++(-60:1) --
  ++(-1,0) --
  ++(180-\Angle:6pt) --
  ++(1,0) --
  cycle;
\draw (aux) -- ++(-\Angle:6pt);

% the helping lines
\begin{scope}[
>=latex,
help lines
]
\foreach \Valor in {4,6,8}
  \draw (\Valor,1.5) -- coordinate (cota\Valor) ++(0,14pt);
\draw[<->] (cota4) -- node[fill=white] {$-2$} (cota6);
\draw[<->] (cota6) -- node[fill=white] {$2$} (cota8);
\foreach \Valor in {2,6,10}
  \draw (\Valor,2.2) -- coordinate (cota\Valor) ++(0,14pt);
\draw[<->] (cota2) -- node[fill=white] {$-4$} (cota6);
\draw[<->] (cota10) -- node[fill=white] {$4$} (cota6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Gonzalo for your nice answer. Would appreciate if you guide me how to help lines if data points are `2, 4, 6, 8 and 10` rather than `3, 4 and 8`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 If you take an effort and just *read* the source Gonzalo posted, the answer to your question will become clear. If what you try doesn't work, at least you can say you put in some amount of effort.

Comment: Take a look especially at the lines that say `foreach`.

Comment: Got what desired. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I added a little example; comparing both examples you can now easily see how to produce a desired combination.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina for your favor. I already got it. For `2 and 10`, deviations should be `-4 and +4` respectively.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Hehe! Of course. Fixed.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I updated my answer and now everything is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina for your time and effort. I have another question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176465/4821). Would appreciate your help for this too. Thanks

Comment: This website is amazing. Even on a question with -3 votes the guy gets a fantastic answer with 17 upvotes...

Comment: I switched from `Windows 7` to `Ubuntu 14.04` and the provided code throws the following error: `Package pgfkeys error: i do not know the key '/tikz/peso/.pic'`. Any idea to figure out this issue. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 you are using an outdated version of PGF/TikZ. Please update the packages.